# Tengo un problema de backtracking

Tags: python

Estoy intentando resolver el problema airplane schedule donde recibo una lista de aviones lo cuales debo de parquearlos de tal manera de que al ubicar uno no interfiera con la salida de los demas. Hasta el momento tengo esta alternativa de solucion en python pero tengo un problema con la implementacion de el backtracking, pues el programa deberia imprimirme un diccionario con la ubicacion de donde deberian parquearse los aviones, pero lo que me imprime es un diccionario vacio.
Sample Input
6 4 5
01 .. == .. 02
03 04 .. 05 06
07 08 .. ## 09
10 11 .. .. 12
+1 +2 +3 +4 +5 +6 -6 -5 -4 -3 -2 -1
Sample Output
Case 1: Yes
12 09 05 06 02 10

```
def movimientoValido(matriz, filas, columnas, parqueaderosAsignados):
  if matriz[filas][columnas] == "##":
    return False
  if not matriz[filas][columnas].isdigit():
    return False
  if matriz[filas][columnas] in parqueaderosAsignados.values():
    return False
  return True


def backtrack(matriz, listaEventos, indiceAvion, parqueaderosAsignados):
  if indiceAvion == len(listaEventos):
    return True

  actual = listaEventos[indiceAvion]

  if actual > 0:  # Aterrizando
    for filas in range(len(matriz)):
      for columnas in range(len(matriz[0])):
        if movimientoValido(matriz, filas, columnas, parqueaderosAsignados):
          parqueaderosAsignados[indiceAvion] = matriz[filas][columnas]
          if backtrack(matriz, listaEventos, indiceAvion + 1, parqueaderosAsignados):
            return True
          parqueaderosAsignados[indiceAvion] = ""
  return False


def recibirMatriz():
  parqueaderosAsignados = {}
  numeroAviones, filas, columnas = map(int, input().split())
  if numeroAviones == 0:
    return False

  matriz = []
  for _ in range(filas):
    matriz.append(input().split())

  listaEventos = list(map(int, input().split()))

  for i in range(numeroAviones):
    parqueaderosAsignados[i] = ""

  backtrack(matriz, listaEventos, 0, parqueaderosAsignados)

  # Imprimir el resultado de la asignación de parqueaderos
  print(parqueaderosAsignados.values())

def main():
  while True:
    if not recibirMatriz():
      break


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```

Answer (score 0):

El problema en tu código es que estás imprimiendo los valores del diccionario `parqueaderosAsignados` en vez de las llaves (es decir, los índices de los aviones). Como los índices son números enteros, al imprimirlos con la función `print()` te dará como resultado una lista de enteros en lugar de un diccionario.

Para imprimir el diccionario como se indica en el enunciado del problema, puedes utilizar el siguiente código después de la llamada a la función `backtrack()`:

```
if backtrack(matriz, listaEventos, 0, parqueaderosAsignados):
  print("Case {}: Yes".format(numCasos))
  print(" ".join([parqueaderosAsignados[i] for i in range(numeroAviones)]))
else:
  print("Case {}: No".format(numCasos))
```

Esto imprimirá el diccionario `parqueaderosAsignados` en el orden de los índices de los aviones. Nota que también se ha agregado un mensaje de "No" en caso de que no se encuentre una solución.

Finalmente, se debe agregar un contador de casos `numCasos` que se incremente en cada iteración del ciclo `while` en la función `main()`, y que se utilice en los mensajes de salida.

El código completo quedaría así:

```
def movimientoValido(matriz, filas, columnas, parqueaderosAsignados):
  if matriz[filas][columnas] == "##":
    return False
  if not matriz[filas][columnas].isdigit():
    return False
  if matriz[filas][columnas] in parqueaderosAsignados.values():
    return False
  return True


def backtrack(matriz, listaEventos, indiceAvion, parqueaderosAsignados):
  if indiceAvion == len(listaEventos):
    return True

  actual = listaEventos[indiceAvion]

  if actual > 0:  # Aterrizando
    for filas in range(len(matriz)):
      for columnas in range(len(matriz[0])):
        if movimientoValido(matriz, filas, columnas, parqueaderosAsignados):
          parqueaderosAsignados[indiceAvion] = matriz[filas][columnas]
          if backtrack(matriz, listaEventos, indiceAvion + 1, parqueaderosAsignados):
            return True
          parqueaderosAsignados[indiceAvion] = ""
  return False


def recibirMatriz(numCasos):
  parqueaderosAsignados = {}
  numeroAviones, filas, columnas = map(int, input().split())
  if numeroAviones == 0:
    return False

  matriz = []
  for _ in range(filas):
    matriz.append(input().split())

  listaEventos = list(map(int, input().split()))

  for i in range(numeroAviones):
    parqueaderosAsignados[i] = ""

  if backtrack(matriz, listaEventos, 0, parqueaderosAsignados):
    print("Case {}: Yes".format(numCasos))
    print(" ".join([parqueaderosAsignados[i] for i in range(numeroAviones)]))
  else:
    print("Case {}: No".format(numCasos))

  return True


def main():
  numCasos = 1
  while recibirMatriz(numCasos):
    numCasos +=
```

Espero que te haya sido de ayuda ;)